# Want public variable to store IP address value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ip

I am looking for the Localhost IP address 192.168.0.x .  I have found the code which can find the Localhost IP address.

However, i want to store the value into a variable which can let other functions to access it.   Like var IPaddress = "192.168.0.x";

I am new and i dont know how to do it. can anyone tell me?  thanks a lot

```
var IPaddress;
$( document ).ready(function() {

    findIP(function(ip) {
        IPaddress = ip
    });

    new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), "http://google.com");
    console.log(IPaddress);


});




function findIP(onNewIP) { //  onNewIp - your listener function for new IPs
    var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection; //compatibility for firefox and chrome
    var pc = new myPeerConnection({iceServers: []}),
            noop = function() {},
            localIPs = {},
            ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
            key;

    function ipIterate(ip) {
        if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
        localIPs[ip] = true;
    }
    pc.createDataChannel(""); //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createOffer(function(sdp) {
        sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
            if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
            line.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
        });
        pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
    }, noop); // create offer and set local description
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) { //listen for candidate events
        if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
        ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
    };
}

function addIP(ip) {
    console.log(ip);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also explicitly set that variable as a property of `window` to make it globally accessible.

```
findIP(function(ip) {
  window.IPaddress = ip
})
```

---

Edit

To store a value in a global variable, just define it in the global scope

```
var ipAddress = getIPAddress() // assumes you have a function for this
```

or

```
window.ipAddress = getIPAddress()
```

Any variable that's declared outside of a function is a global variable.

```
// global variable
var someGlobalThing = 'something global'

function someFunction() {
  // local variable
  var someLocalThing = 'something local'
  console.log(someGlobalThing) // logs 'something global'
}

console.log(someLocalThing) // logs undefined
```

Comment: i cannot access the value in IPaddress variable, turns out to be "undefine"

Comment: I want to store the value into a variable and use that variable in other function

Comment: Okay, that wasn't clear in your question. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define the `var` outside any function and it is global and accessible by all other functions.  It is said to have global scope.

```
var test = "this is a test";
var test2 = false;
```

Render in your browser, open your browsers developer console and type `test` and you will get the below.  Reset it from the console to prove to yourself that you have access to write it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

findIP has asynchronous calls.

In your exemple, the console.log happens before the callback function is invoked.

You want to put other functions that need to access to the ip argument inside the callback:

```
findIP(function(ip) {
    console.log(ip);
    // other functions
});
```